# Grey image without try_key

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an application which captures frame from camera and then it shows the picture as imshow() like that:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);

if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }

while (true) {
        bool bSuccess = cap.read(imgOriginal); // read a new frame from video
        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
            cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
            break;
        }

cv::imshow("Image", imgOriginal);

if (waitKey(10) == 27)
        {
            break;
            return 1;
        }
}
```

And the program works well. But when I delete wait_key loop and instead of that give some other handle (for example variable which can describe if while loop is ok or even if, but instead wait_key(10) == 27 I put checkVariable == false), everything goes wrong. I get grey image instead of normal picture. Can you explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `waitKey` function is not only to get a key from the user, it also does the equivalent to `spin` in other GUI frameworks. This means that it also "updates" any event of the window displaying the image, such as display a new image (it starts with default value gray most probably). So, you HAVE to use the function whenever you use `imshow` at least. It also does a small pause (number of milliseconds given as argument) so you can use it to avoid idle loops to occupy a CPU like crazy.

You can always ignore the result of waitKey if you do not need it, but it has to run.

I hope this clears your doubt.